# override class or subclassing in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uipagecontrol, uistoryboard, uipageviewcontroller

I'm having issues assigning a custom class in storyboard.

In past projects I have overridden/subclassed `UIPageControl` to a custom class (`ZZPageControl`) by adding the .h to the view with the `UIPageControl`.

```
#import "MyPageControl.h"
@interface ScrollerVC : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    IBOutlet MyPageControl *pageControl;
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers;
    BOOL pageControlUsed;
}
```

Then in IB I assign my custom class instead of `UIPageControl`.

Except my new project uses Storyboard rather than separate XIBs. When selecting the `UIPageControl` in the view and checking its class in the Identity Inspector only `UIPageControl` is listed. If I type `MyPageControl` is doesn't stick.

I've tried adding `#import "MyPageControl.h"` in the app delegate, in the view that initiates the `UINavigation` control, in the .pch file. I can't get my custom class to show up in the Storyboard.

How can I override the `UIPageControl` in the StoryBoard view?

Comment: I'm assuming you correctly subclassed UIPageControl in `MyPageControl.h`...`@interface MyPageControl : UIPageControl`? Is `MyPageControl` a linked class or is directly in your project?

Comment: @Gobot Yes indeed, as I mentioned I've used it in previous projects. The difference is in Storyboard 'UIPageControl' is the *only* class listed in the Identity Inspector

Comment: You ran a **clean** and **rebuild**? Everything still compiling with no warnings?

Comment: Yep. In the past the inspector has shown all classes available, the Storyboard just show the one class, hence I can't override. Can I reassign the class programatically?

Comment: Try starting a new temp project, drag your `MyPageControl` class into the project, and see if you can can assign it to a `UIPageControl` in a Storyboard. That would at least tell us if your XCode project is corrupt, or if something's up in your class.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the issue - Storyboard only shows the  recommended class for an object, ie UIPageControl or UIButton. Whereas IN used to show ALL classes available to the project. So there is no way to specify a custom class.

Comment: Right, I think in the current version it doesn't show a list of classes. But that doesn't matter, you can still type in your custom subclass in that field. But you said you typed it before and it didn't work/stick. That makes me think that either your project is corrupt/not indexing your class files correctly, or something is a little off in your class, even though you used that class for previous XCode versions.

Comment: OK, I'll give it another, the class does appear in the listing for a UIView so it's been added, and I've used the class successfully in projects with no storyboard.

Comment: This is an old question but it might still be useful to look into it. Did you fix it? Could you add the headerfile of the `MyPageControl` class to your question?